# Jquery event in manipulated content by another script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have page where an external script manipulates the content. The completion of manipulation takes a while depending on connection speed, etc.

What i want to do is to change attributes of some elements in manipulated content. When i try

```
$('#confirmButton').remove();
```

it doesn't work as the button does not exist at the time of running this jquery function.

What can i do to wait for the manipulation to complete, and then run my Jquery manipulations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by calling the external script from within jquery

```
$.getScript("http://externalscript.js", function(){
    //alert("Script loaded and executed.");

    //call remove function a bit later in case manipulation takes long
    window.setTimeout(function (){ $('#confirmButton').remove(); }, 500);
});
```